# Will android 5.0.1 sdk package work for android 5.0.4?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have Android 5.0.4, so which **Android SDK** package do I need to Install?

[image: Android SDK]

There are two Options available in Android SDK Manager

- ANDROID 5.1.1
- ANDROID 5.0.1

My Device : 5.0.4

Answer (score 1):

Always try to install the latest `SDK` as they always provides the `backward compatibility` so you wouldn't have any issues in running your code which on a lower version of `Android`.

Hope it helps!

Comment: So Should I go with ANDROID 5.1.1 or ANDROID 6.0? According to your statement I think both will be going to work. Correct me if needed

Answer (score 0):

Install the latest SDK . but in your case API 21 should do fine as well